# How can I change the colour of a slider after its creation?

Tags: matplotlib, user-interface, widget, slider, interactive

I would like to change the slider cooler from red to blue in the example below. I tried the `set_facecolor` method but it does not work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.6, 0.2, 0.25, 0.03])
slider = Slider(ax, 'Slider', 0,  1, facecolor='r')
slider.ax.set_facecolor('b')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

```
slider.poly.set_fc('b')
```